# Uniqueness in boundary value problem for the biharmonic functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

[image]

**My attempt:**

I tried to use the Green's representation formula twice.

The Green's reprensentation formula:$u(y)=\int_{\partial \Omega}(u(x)\frac{\partial G(x-y)}{\partial v}-G(x-y)\frac {\partial u(x)}{\partial v})dx+\int_\Omega G(x-y)\triangle u(x)dx$

First apply the formula to $\triangle u(y)$. I get

$\triangle u(y)=\int_{\partial \Omega}(\triangle u(x)\frac{\partial G(x-y)}{\partial v}-G(x-y)\frac {\partial \triangle u(x)}{\partial v})dx+\int_\Omega G(x-y)\triangle\triangle u(x)dx$

**By assumption in the problem, $\triangle u(y)=0$.**

Apply Green's representation formula again:

$u(y)=\int_{\partial \Omega}(u(x)\frac{\partial G(x-y)}{\partial v}-G(x-y)\frac {\partial u(x)}{\partial v})dx+\int_\Omega G(x-y)\triangle u(x)dx$

I get $u(u)=0$.

**My problem:**

I feel confused **about this step in my proof(the part in bold)** and I feel it is insufficient.

Can anyone give me some clues or answers! **That will be extremely helpful! Thanks so much! :>**

Comment: I don't see how you conclude $\triangle u(y)=0$ there. For this boundary value problem, uniqueness is usually proved via Lax-Milgram lemma, see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/156366/147263).

Comment: @CareBear Because $u=\frac {\partial u}{\partial v}=0$ on $\partial \Omega$? Then can I conclude that $\triangle u=\frac {\partial \triangle u}{\partial v}=0$ on $\partial \Omega$? Then the first part of the equation is 0 and the second part is also 0, then $\triangle u=0$.

Comment: @CareBear I am sorry to bother you but is this correct？

Comment: Absolutely not. It's like in one dimensions: you can have $f(a)=f'(a)=0$ but $f''(a)$ and $f'''(a)$ may well be nonzero. If you knew that the Laplacian of $u$ is zero on the boundary, this would be an easier problem, and then your approach would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comments, I do not find the conclusion $\Delta u(y)=0$ justified. Here is a different approach.

Let $v=\Delta u$. Since both $u$ and its normal derivative vanish on the boundary, [Green's second identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_identities#Green.27s_second_identity) implies
$$\int_\Omega (v\Delta u - u \Delta v) = 0 $$ 
which simplifies to 
$$\int_\Omega (\Delta u)^2 = 0 $$ 
Thus, $u$ is harmonic. Since it has zero boundary values, it is identically zero.