# a nontrivial inequality in the proof of weak solution of biharmonic equation

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Hi I am looking at the post discussed about weak solution of biharmonic equation
[Unique weak solution to the biharmonic equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156366/proving-unique-weak-solution)

I am having trouble verifying statement 2: The bilinear operator is coercive,
The claim is
$$B(u,u)=\int_|\Delta\,u|^2=\|\Delta u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2\ge C\|u\|_{H_0^2(\Omega)}^2$$

I have read the hint (commented by Shuhao Cao) and still couldn't get it. Could any one show me explicitly how the above could be true?

Many thanks!

Comment: Take a look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301404/eqiuvalent-norms-in-h-02

Answer (score 1):

If we are on $H^2_0$, then both $u$ and it's first order derivatives are zero on the boundary (let's do this in $2$D, since it generalises easily), and so we see that
$$\|\Delta u\|_2^2=\int_\Omega u_{xx}^2+2u_{xy}^2+u_{yy}^2=2\int_\Omega u_{xx}^2+u_{yy}^2=2|u|_{H^2}^2,$$
note that the latter equality is deduced by integrating by parts, possibly arguing by approximation.

Now we use poincare inequality, which tells us that $\|u\|_{2}\le C_1\|\nabla u\|_2\le C_2|u|_{H^2}$, and thus
$$\|u\|_{H^2_0}^2=\|u\|_2^2+\|\nabla u\|_2^2+|u|_{H^2}^2\le C|u|_{H^2}^2=\frac{1}{2}C\|\Delta u\|_2^2. $$
The rest follows.

Comment: Note that I have used poincare for the function and the gradient because $u\in H^2_0$ implies that the function **and** it's derivatives are zero on the boundary

Answer (score 0):

I realize that the OP has probably long since moved on from this question, but I thought I'd post an alternate answers for future readers.

Actually, this claim follows from the discussion of elliptic regularity in Evans' book, c.f. Theorem 4 in Section 6.3.2. Indeed, choose $u\in H^2_0(U)$ and put $g=\Delta u$. Note that (trivially) $u$ solves the system 
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{lcl}
\Delta u = g & & \text{ in } U \\
u = 0 & & \text{ on } \partial U
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Then we have the estimate 
$$
\|u\|_{H^2(U)}\le c_0(\|g\|_{L^2(U)} + \|u\|_{L^2(U)}),
$$
for some constant $c$ depending on $U$. Next, by Theorem 6 in Section 6.2.3 (Evans' book again), $\Delta^{-1}$ is bounded in the sense that $\|u\|_{L^2(U)}\le c_1\|g\|_{L^2(U)}$.  Therefore the above estimate simplifies to 
$$
\|u\|_{H^2(U)}\le c_2\|g\|_{L^2(U)} = c_2\|\Delta u\|_{L^2(U)}.
$$
Take $C = c_2^{-2}$ to prove the claim.